# Container Optimized VM - How to force pulling from registry (and not using local image:tag)?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build

I am using Google Cloud Build to build containers run on Container Optimized OS VM's on several projects

A typical `cloudbuild.yaml` file looks like this:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ "build",
    "-t", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/core-app-${BRANCH_NAME}:latest",
    "."]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/core-app-${BRANCH_NAME}:latest"]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ["beta", "compute", "instances", "update-container", "core-app-${BRANCH_NAME}", "--container-image", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/core-app-${BRANCH_NAME}:latest", "--zone", "${_ZONE}"]
images:
- "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/core-app-${BRANCH_NAME}:latest"
```

A trigger is defined with some branch condition

In essence, on a commit to a given branch, an image with tag `latest` is built and used to run a container of a given VM.

It worked great until a couple of weeks ago. And suddenly, on all projects, it stopped working well. Instead of pulling `latest` the VM keeps using the local one. The only workaround I found was to use a SHA as tag (`gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/core-app-${BRANCH_NAME}:${SHORT_SHA}`), but this results in several images accumulating on the VM and at some point, there is not enough space anymore and the deployment fails.

So, how can I force the container optimized VM to pull an image:tag when it has one with the same name on the local disk?

Comment: - Could you share more information on how you pull the image? Are you doing it manually through the command line, or are you automating it with a yaml file?   
  
- You’ve also said that there is not enough space anymore once all the images are accumulating. Are you referring to space in the VM instance, or space in the Google Container registry (Cloud Storage)?

Comment: @mahmoudSharif - Sorry for the late reply
I don't pull the image explicitly, I just update the image name with the latest cloud build step in the yaml file. when I use the "latest" tag, the VM keeps using the local image instead of pulling the one just built. Also, the GCS bucket where artifacts are stored is in a different region (US/Multi) than the VM (south east asia)

I am referring to the disk space on the VM (default 10 gb drive). This pb only occurs when using the ${SHORT_SHA} as tag instead of "latest".

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the old images before you pull in the new ones, by utilizing a command like

> `docker image prune -a -f`

You would get a higher downtime while updating from one version to another, but if that is not really an issue for you then this should work just fine.